# Legal implications of this prank going horribly wrong?

Tags: criminal-law, homicide, suicide, manslaughter

I remembered coming across this comic from [Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal](http://smbc-comics.com).

[image: Tommy, the Office Prankster]

In this comic, Tommy replaces his boss' gun with a fake that just shoots out a "Bang!" flag.  Later, he breaks into his office and pretends to be a robber, presumably expecting his boss to try to defend himself with the fake gun.  However, his boss committed suicide, and happened to use the fake gun.

**Assume the following:**

- Tommy did not steal the real gun, he hid it elsewhere in his boss' office.
- Tommy has a job where he could plausibly need access to his boss' office (maybe an IT guy or something), so he has a key.
- Tommy did not intend to actually hurt his boss.
- Tommy's boss' suicide was entirely intentional, and he would've died even if Tommy had never attempted the prank.
- There was no suicide note.
- State and country doesn't actually matter, because I'm curious as to how different systems might handle such a strange situation.

**My questions are as follows:**

1. Is Tommy guilty of any crime?
2. If his boss *didn't* commit suicide, and tried to defend himself against the "robber" as planned, would Tommy be guilty of a crime even if ultimately no one was actually hurt?
3. If a *real* robber had broken into the boss' office before Tommy had a chance to play his prank, and the boss was unable to defend himself as a result, what charges would Tommy be facing?
4. Could his boss sue him if the scenarios in (2) or (3) came to pass?

Comment: Surely the answers depend on the jurisdiction.

Comment: Yes, it does, and that only makes me more curious.

Comment: How do you commit suicide with a fake gun?

Comment: @Mohair because of an unexpected effect that is nonetheless fatal.

Comment: @Mohair Read the comic!

Comment: Looking at the picture, it seems the boss is too far gone to sue anyone.

Comment: A question you could add: If he broke into the office pretending to be a robber, the boss tried first to shoot him with the fake gun, then hit the prankster really hard over the head with the fake gun causing severe injury, could the boss be sued?

Comment: If you can commit suicide with a fake gun, then i think there is a pretty good case for a lawsuit

Comment: @gnasher729 I can't remember if it was you that I mentioned this to, but the person who is wronged is not the only one who can bring suit against a defendant. If this were the case, murder/manslaughter would not be a crime.

Comment: The situation seems to be: There was a lethal weapon. The prankster swapped it with a less dangerous weapon. The boss committed suicide and it "worked" exactly as it would have happened with the original weapon. A much more difficult question: If the prankster's action made the boss survive, with a $500,000 hospital bill, or permanent health damage, which would _not_ have happened with the original weapon, would the prankster be responsible?

Comment: @gnasher729 in response to your question, I think not! There is an inherent assumption of risk when one aims a gun at themselves and shoots it.

Comment: Just to be sure: Did Tommy’s boss commit suicide _upon_ Tommy entering the room? As soon he heard someone at the door? Or was the boss already dead as a dodo for, say, 20 minutes? [And, just out of curiosity, are you, I mean, “someone you know” planning such a “prank”?]

Comment: @KaiBurghardt 1) Dead as a dodo before Tommy entered. 2) No, I've never done this nor do I plan to. I'll say the same thing under oath. I just like asking weird questions (or questions about weird scenarios) because the answers can take you to interesting places.

Comment: It seems more succinct to make a statement to the effect of are there legal implications for denying someone suicide where they choose to do so (the opposite of assisted sucicide) and what about intentionally depriving someone of the means to defend themselves (as might happen in many managerial situations where the automotons start stepping outside their boundaries). What happens when a system is subverted and tangential solutions cause real harm?

Answer (score 1):

In Canada, I think Tommy would be found guilty of [*criminal negligence causing death.*](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/page-51.html#h-76)

> **Criminal negligence**
>
> 219 (1) Every one is criminally negligent who
> (a) in doing anything, or
> (b) in omitting to do anything that it is his duty to do,
> shows wanton or reckless disregard for the lives or safety of other persons.
>
> (2) For the purposes of this section, duty means a duty imposed by law.
>
> **Causing death by criminal negligence**
>
> 220 Every person who by criminal negligence causes death to another person is guilty of an indictable offence and liable
>
> (a) where a firearm is used in the commission of the offence, to imprisonment for life and to a minimum punishment of imprisonment for a term of four years; and
> (b) in any other case, to imprisonment for life.

Tommy didn't show any consideration for the safety of his boss, and even though he didn't directly kill him, he showed disregard for him. The fright Tommy caused his boss eventually caused his death (had Tommy been a real robber, he could've been charged with first-degree murder).

2. Probably not: if nothing happens, then it will probably be taken as a good ol' prank.
3. Probably be charged with criminal negligence, assuming that Tommy took no action to assist his boss after realizing the situation.
4. This would likely be a civil case, rather than a criminal one. I'm not too familiar with civil law, but I wouldn't be surprised if assault came into play.

Comment: I don't think that conduct is wanton or reckless. It may be negligent, at most, but it doesn't rise to the level of criminal negligence.

Comment: @Viktor I would see it as either being criminal negligence or manslaughter. I opted for the negligence charge mostly because Tommy wasn't necessarily the one causing the death, but he showed disregard for the safety of his boss. I'm using Canadian law here, and section 222(5)(c) reads *"by causing that human being, by threats or fear of violence or by deception, to do anything that causes his death;"* - I could probably be successful in finding him guilty of manslaughter if I wanted to.

Comment: the fact that the boss shot himself doesn't play into that?

Comment: @Viktor What do you mean? Are you suggesting that Tommy didn't actually do anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, aside from potentially violating gun laws.

Comment: I don't read the comic to mean that Tommy pretending to be a robber caused his boss' suicide. Note that his boss' hand has had time to drop away from the gun. Although you can't see it, he is probably sitting at his desk. He committed suicide some time in the half-hour window between Tommy swapping the gun and bursting in pretending to be a robber. Both guns in the comic are potentially fatal, but the fake gun is much less likely to cause death. I would assume that it penetrated soft tissue instead of bone to cause his boss' death. The suicide was not precipitated by Tommy swapping the guns.

Comment: @CJDennis Aye, but one way to look at it - is that Tommy caused the death by wilfully causing his boss' freight, and was reckless in his role to keep him safe. I probably should've recommended manslaughter as the charge - as it is, he didn't *mean* to kill him, but his actions led to that.

Comment: Do you mean fright or is freight a legal term? That question is not sarcastic. Do you mean that Tommy should have foreseen the possibility of his boss' suicide and removed all guns from his office?

Comment: @CJDennis Well, yes. It's culpable homicide, and one way to commit is it by wilfully causing fear to someone that causes there death. However, in the Criminal Code of Canada, the victim must be a child or a sick person, so I'm not sure how that plays out. But consider manslaughter - if you punch someone in the face and they die because of that, you can be charged and convicted. You did something to hurt them, you may not have foreseen their death, but they still died. That's manslaughter (this really should be manslaughter)... Oh, and I meant fright, not freight :)

Comment: If the boss committed suicide 15 minutes before Tommy came bursting in (which is how I interpret it) how did he cause his boss to be afraid? He replaced a real gun with a fake gun that looked similar enough that his boss mistook it for the real thing. A bullet would have killed his boss just as surely (unless his boss was in the habit of sticking an unloaded gun in his mouth and pulling the trigger without first checking the barrels). The boss intended to commit suicide with a bullet, independently of Tommy bursting in 15 minutes later, but died from a stick through his brain instead.

Comment: I don't think too many gun owner's first reaction to a robbery would be to shoot *themselves*... he was obviously already dead.

Comment: @CJDennis Wait what? I interpreted it that the boss was so frightened by Tommy that he ended up committing suicide. I'm really confused now...

Comment: Plot twist: Tommy's boss thought his actual gun to be unloaded and was just clowning around.

Comment: I don't think the criminal negligence duty arises without a foreseeable harm which successful suicide with the fake gun is not.